# I'm solidifying a mesh and want to bevel just the cap. How can I avoid that the bevel also rounds the outline of the mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I have a flat mesh of the letter 'A'. I would like that the front face has a nice bevel. However, I would also like that the shape of the letter (when seen from the front) stays the same. With the bevel modifier, this is not the case. It will round the shape of the letter (as indicated with red circles on the picture below).

I'm already using a Angle limit method on the bevel, or else it would add a lot of unnecessary vertices.

I'd like to stay in a non-destructive workflow, and would like to avoid applying the modifiers.

[image: Image for clarification of my modifier stack]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. First, in edit mode, you select the edge of your flat mesh, and go to Edge -> Edge Bevel Weight. Then you press 1 on the numpad or drag your mouse to set the weight. The edge will become blue.

[image: Bevel Weights]

Then, in the Bevel modifier, you change the limit method to "Weight".

[image: Modifier settings]

And this has the desired effect! I thought that it would work the same as the "Vertex Group" limit, but with the vertex group, you add unnecessary bevels in a lot of places because you're almost selecting all of your vertices.

[image: Final topology]